# How to get ID of the clicked element and store in variable and use it in function that makes AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have been trying to remove this `#static` id from the one click function below and make a use of variable so that it automatically gets the Ids' like `#static`, `#dynamic`...etc and puts it in One click function. This will save me copying and pasting the same function again and again just by changing it's ID names. Plus this will also make the code look clean & short.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
// Home Page Static Portfolio Ajax Query
$(this).one('click', '#static', function( e ){
    var that = $(this);
    var id = that.attr('id');
    var rel = that.data('rel');
    var ajaxurl = that.data('url');
    $.ajax({
        url : ajaxurl,
        type : 'POST',
        data : {
            rel : rel,
            action : 'home_filter_' + id + '_portfolios'
        },
        error : function( response ){
            console.log( response );
        },
        success : function ( response ){
            if ( response == '' ) {
                $('figure' + id).after( '<div class="end_of_testimonial"><h3>You have reached the end of the line</h3><p>No more portfolios to load!</p></div>' );
            } else {
                $('.gallery-wrapper').append( response );
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: If that isn't just about using `.on()` instead of `.one()`... Please edit your question. Your issue could be better defined. What is the *help* you expect?

Answer (score 2):

You can use class and call this way to ajax function. Here is your demo code. You can use as many as id you want for this functions. I use document on event for called every instance of that class.
[Fiddel link](https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/19246/)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    // Home Page Static Portfolio Ajax Query
    $(document).on('click', '.clickclass', function( e ){
        var that = $(this);
        var id = that.attr('id');
        var rel = that.data('rel');
        var ajaxurl = that.data('url');
            alert(id);

    });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a common class to all the elements you want this to work on and use a regular `on()`

Add another class when one has been clicked so you don't make the request again as replacement for `one()` functionality

```js
$(function() {
  // better to use `document` instead of `this` for readability
  $(document).on('click', '.my-div', function(e) {
    var that = $(this);
    if (that.hasClass('already-clicked')) {
      // bail out
      console.log('Already clicked')
      return
    } else {
      that.addClass('already-clicked');
      var data = that.data();
      data.id = this.id;
      console.log(JSON.stringify(data))
      // do your ajax
    }
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="my-div" id="1" data-rel="rel_1" data-url="url_1">Div one</div>
<div class="my-div" id="2" data-rel="rel_2" data-url="url_2">Div two</div>
<div class="my-div" id="3" data-rel="rel_3" data-url="url_3">Div two</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
$(this).one('click', '#static', function( e )
```

In this line of your code you should use class as an identifier of the element. "id" is unique and it should be assigned to only one element.

```
$(body).one('click', '.yourclass', function( e )
```

and add the class to all the element you want.

Comment: Sorry the final code is
$(body).one('click', '.yourclass', function( e )

Comment: Won't work since clicking any of that class using `one()` will prevent code running on other elements with that class